# Talis over head

Tags: tefilla, ashkenazi, tallit-gadol, head

Why is it that most Ashkenazim that are not married do not put the Talis over their head?

Comment: HOw about why they dont wear a tallis at all?

Comment: That would be a seperate question. However even those that do wear a Talis prior to their wedding - or when a Bochur gets an Aliyah -  they do not wear the Talis over their head. Why not?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7724/759

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The minhag is sourced to the Talmud ([Kiddushin 29b](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9B%D7%98_%D7%91)) that only married men would put the talis over their heads.

`א"ל מאי טעמא לא פריסת סודרא א"ל דלא נסיבנא`

Rashi: `דלא פריס סודר - כדרך הנשואין שהיו רגילין לכסות ראשן`

Comment: Yekkes derive from the same source that only a talmid chacham should cover his head, and from what I have heard, only during Amidah.

Answer (score 7):

so that woman who are looking to get married may see who is and is not married.

Comment: Koachyah, very funny!

Comment: Nice bit of humor!