# Talis Gadol for Unmarried Individuals

Tags: minhag, marriage, tallit-gadol

In my minhag (and I believe it's minhag Ashkenaz), unmarried men do not wear a Talis Gadol (only a Talis Katan).

Why is this so?

Comment: I have heard that this originated in Europe as an incentive for young men to get married. No source, though.

Comment: The Yekkes wear a talis Gadol from Bar Mitzva however they do not cover their head with the Talis until marriage.

Comment: @GershonGold, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3131

Comment: An answer to this question, different from the one offered in the answer below, is in [_Taame Haminhagim_ 967](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&pgnum=423), but I don't understand it, so am not writing it as an answer.

Comment: Ashkenaz, but not Germany

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83935

Comment: Radak Shmuel 1:2:19

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In [*D'varim* 22](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%91), the [*pasuk* commanding placement of *tzitziyos*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%91) on 4-cornered garments immediately precedes the [*pasuk* describing/commanding getting married](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%92). The juxtaposition gave rise to the *minhag* of simultanaizing these two acts.

Extracting instructive meaning from the juxtaposition of two verses is [universally acceptable](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=4&format=pdf) as a method of interpretation only in *D'varim*. The example used by the *g'mara* to prove this includes one of the aforementioned *p'sukim*. In [this issue](http://www.etzion.org.il/dk/5767/1091mamar1.html) of Yeshivat Har Etzion's *Daf Kesher*, the topic is addressed. Its mention is attributed to the *Sefer Hamanhig*, on whom the *Mishna B'rura* asks exactly @jake's question in the comment below: How could it be that a *mitzva* from the Torah is pushed off beyond the age of *bar mitzva*?

It is suggested that although an interesting symbolic connection exists between wrapping *oneself* in a *talis* and protecting one's wife or imitating God's ways, citing the *pasuk* is intended to be a postfix hint and not an *ab initio* source.

(Also see this Satmar publication for extensive treatment of the same question: [פרי תמרים](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13355&st=&pgnum=67))

Comment: "Extracting instructive meaning from the juxtaposition of two verses" is only acceptable as a method of rabbinic midrash halacha. Never before have I heard of such a method being used to provide for "giving rise to a minhag", especially one that counters the general idea of one being obligated in mitzvos from bar mitzva age.

Comment: Good point. It needs explanation. Stay tuned for more.

Comment: Re "citing the pasuk is intended to be a postfix hint and not an *ab initio* source." Great way of describing *derech asmachta*. Also, the article in *P'ri T'marim*, in my opinion, does a better job of justifying the minhag. I would recommend summarizing its conclusion as part of your answer.

Comment: @jake - Coming right up.

Comment: In minhag Ashkenaz, paseukim are frequently darshened in ways not found in Chazal in order to justify minhagim. Aside from tzitzit, another example is the minhag of not praying ma'ariv of shavuot before tzait hakochavim. This comes from the paseuk of sefira being "seven **complete** weeks". However the first person to justify this minhag was R' Avraham Horowitz, the father of the Shelah HaKadosh, which means this justification significantly postdates chazal.

Comment: Wearing a talit gadol is not a Mitzva. Putting strings on if you happen to wear one is. I don't see where the presumption of difficulty comes from.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, You are correct that wearing a talit gadol is not a mitzva, and perhaps @WAF's phrasing of the question is a little misleading. Talit gadol is a minhag that is based on the importance of both tefilla and the mitzva of wearing tzitzit. Since both of these are general obligations that kick in at bar mitzva age, there is a difficulty in understanding why this minhag does not apply until marriage.

Comment: @jake That's fine. I just wanted to make clear that the difficulty is not at the level of "why is this novel drasha pushing off a Biblical commandment?"

Answer (score 10):

[The B'nei Yissachar says](http://www.tsel.org/torah/bneiyis/part2/107.html) that kabalistically, a Talit Gadol draws down an Or Makif (Transcendent Light). This can only be drawn down when a person is joyful (with Simcha Shel Mitzvah).  Since the Gemara says ([Yevamot 62B](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1703&size=1))  "A man without a wife lives without joy", and ([Shabbos 152A](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=426&size=2)) "The joy of the heart is a woman" an unmarried person does not wear a Talit Gadol.

(I found this in "[Tzitzit - Halacha Lema'aseh](http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?stocknumber=HL-TZIT&deptid=3269&parentid=83&page=5&itemsperpage=10)")

Comment: Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing in this idea!

Comment: The spouse serving as a •Makif*, an internalizer of the holiness of the *Neshama* to the righteous, scholarly person, is referred to in Chapter 8 (*The Five Parts of the Soul*) of the holy book *[Flames of Faith](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/760828)* by Rabbi Zev Reichman, on page 82.

Answer (score 8):

There is no chiyuv to wear Tzitzis unless you are wearing a 4-cornered garment. That used to be what they wore in bavel, but over time the style of clothing changed. It became customary to specifically put on a 4-cornered garment so as to get the mitzvah of Tzitzis. It seems that the custom to wear a large 4-cornered garment was only adopted by married people, perhaps due to financial reasons.

Note that German-Jews do wear Tallesim before marriage, and I think R'Hershel Schachter also thinks its a good idea.

Comment: Not only "German-Jews" (aka Yekkes) but also Sefardim and Teimanim.