# Singles not wear Talit Gadol

Tags: minhag, marriage, tallit-gadol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Talis Gadol for Unmarried Individuals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/talis-gadol-for-unmarried-individuals)

Where did the idea of not wearing Talit Gadol before marriage come from? Also, where did the Minhag of Sefaradim get the Minhag to wear it? (I think the Hesed LaAlafim holds to wear it before marriage, but I bet there are earlier sources).

Comment: duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7724/759

Comment: @DoubleAA that was why.. I want the source.

Comment: @HachamGabriel You mean you don't like the answers there?

Comment: @HachamGabriel You can always start a [bounty](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) if you want better answers.