# Why wear tallis on head at different times of davening?

Tags: tefilla, tallit-gadol

Different people have different customs about covering their heads with their tallis during davening.  For example, some cover their heads for shmoneh esrei, others cover their heads for all of davening, and others cover their heads for more than just shmoneh esrei but not all of davening.  What are the reasons for each of these customs and any other customs that might exist?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15332/reasons-for-different-minhagim-regarding-if-and-when-to-put-tallit-gadol-over-he/17575#17575

Comment: @GeshonGold Isn't that a dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA: It seems like that to me.

Comment: @GershonGold Why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: @DoubleAA: When a new arrival asks a question I like to give him a chance to clarify whether it is the same or different.

Comment: @GershonGold I've now given him a chance. He now has as long a chance as he wants, without having to worry about wasting others' time writing duplicate answers. I'm sure Jack wouldn't want to do that.